# What computational steps needed to characterize the Weyl points?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, topological-insulators, wannier90, weyl-semimetal

I am trying to learn the characterization of Weyl nodes computationally. For this, I am using **Wannier90** and **Z2pack** codes in interface with **Quantum ESPRESSO**. I have done scf, nscf, bands structure, DOS, etc calculations in Quantum ESPRESSO, earlier. I want to learn how I can characterize the presence of Weyl nodes using these codes. I think for this I have to calculate the Chern number for a surface (spherical) which enclosed the Weyl points in k-space. For Weyl nodes, it should be +1 and -1 (opposite chirality).

I want to know, what steps do I have to follow to get the result, eg. in band structure calculation we perform SCF, bands calculation with pw.x executable and then use the bands.x to get the .dat files. What do I have to do in this case?  I have already installed all the codes and interfaces.

I have surfed on the internet a lot but didn't get any clarified tutorial for this. Please share your experience if you have done it. It will be helpful.

Comment: How did this go? Have you found an answer now? It would be nice to get this out of the unanswered queue since it's been there for more than 11 months now! Please update us!

Comment: Any luck with this? Did you figure it out? Are you still working on this?